# Showing multiple images in Matplotlib, and attaching an event to it

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to display multiple images in Matplotlib (in separate windows), and I want each of them to have a different a different `button_press_event` attached to it. Here's what I'm trying.

```py
# t is an array of Path objects, one for each image
# idx is an array with a list of indexes to t
# describing the order in which I want to show the images.

clicked = []

for i, id in enumerate(idx):
    im = imread(t[id]) # skimage.imageio.imread

    fig = plt.figure(id)
    ax = plt.gca(figure=fig)
    implot = ax.imshow(im)

    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', lambda event: clicked.append(id))

    if i == (len(idx) - 1):
        print(id)
        plt.show()
    else:
        plt.show(block=False)

print(clicked)
```

I then click on the figures one at a time, and only once for each.

When I print the value of the `clicked` list, the list always contains only the value of the last `id` in the loop. Suppose `idx = [1, 0]`. Then clicked will always contain [0, 0]. This indicates to me that I'm always attaching the event to the same figure. I, however, can't understand why this is the case, since I'm creating a new figure each time. I'd like to know how to properly attach the `id` to the figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the "id" of the figure through `Figure.number`, but first you need to get a reference to the figure, which you can get through the `event` object:

```
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', lambda event: clicked.append(event.canvas.figure.number))
```

BTW, the line `ax = plt.gca(figure=fig)` throws an exception on my version of matplotlib. I think you should use `ax = fig.add_subplot(111)` instead.